# changing ylim with plot_date python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I cannot figure out how to change the ylim on my yaxis with plot_date and have tried several options including ax.yaxis.set_ticks , plt.gca().set_ylim([start,end]).  The lines being plotted are being cut off and extend over the scale of the y-axis. I am trying to increase the y-axis scale to show 7-09, or at least extend it so my lines are not being cut off.  I have 3 lines on the same figure and maybe it is something to do with each plot command resetting its own limits? Any help is much appreciated.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.plot_date(yearsTotal,dateStr,xdate=False,ydate=True,ls='-',marker='')
plt.plot_date(yearsTotal,dateStrSlope,xdate=False,ydate=True,ls='-',marker='',color='r')
plt.plot_date(YearsNoNans,AvNoNans,xdate=False,ydate=True,ls='-',marker='',color='g')

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))

plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(b=True,which='major',color='b')
plt.tick_params(axis='x',pad=20,labelsize=24)
plt.tick_params(axis='y',labelsize=24)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

problem starts here: start,end,stepsize have no effect. I have also tried the commented out options.

```
start = datetime.date(1953,5,23)
end = datetime.date(1953,7,9)
stepsize=(end-start)/10
#ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start,end,stepsize))
#plt.gca().set_ylim([datetime.date(1953, 5, 23), datetime.date(1953, 7, 9)])
#plt.gca().set_ylim(bottom=end)

locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=0)

ax.axis('tight')
plt.savefig(figPath+'brkDOY.png',bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `ax.axis('tight')` this is overriding the rescaling of yaxis. Try using `plt.tight_layout()`. Here is the code you should have at the end

```
start = datetime.date(1953,5,23)
end = datetime.date(1953,7,9)
ax.set_ylim([start,end])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(figPath+'brkDOY.png',bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

I believe that you can also eliminate

```
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=0)
```

so long as you are using xdate=False. Matplotlib only rotates the x axis labels when the x axis is plotted as dates which you are not.